# Is it possible to check which view is being used inside a region?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, prism

Is it possible to check which view is being used inside a region?
I'm using MVVM.

I got this code at the moment:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            var countactiveviews = RegionManager.Regions.First(x => x.Name == "MainRegion").ActiveViews;

            if (!countactiveviews.Any())
            {
                //// Show preview
                var modulePreview = new Uri(_view.Replace("GridView", "Preview"), UriKind.Relative);
                RegionManager.RequestNavigate(Regions.PropertiesRegion, modulePreview);         
            }

            else
            {

            }
```

When _view is being  used or open at the moment, then I want to execute that code again.

So inside my else:

```
if(_view is being viewed) ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "used"? The `ActiveViews` collection contains all views that are visible/active in the region. Prism provides an `AllActiveRegion` and a `SingleActiveRegion`. `AllActiveRegion` can contain multiple active views and `SingleActiveRegion` only one.

Comment: Yes, but I have a tabcontrol in my shell and I want the view from the tab which is currently being used. Is it possible to get items from the tabcontrol using regionmanager?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a destination where you want to execute your code.

If you are inside a view model, u can put interface **IActiveAware** on your view model. It's provide to you property IsActive and event IsActiveChanged.

If you are outside the view model, you can use **RegionManager**. In each **Region** are Views and ActiveViews collection. You can check **ActiveViews** collection for your view model. Also you can use INotifyCollectionChanged interface for detect active view collection changed. Next what can help you is interface **INavigationAware**. Put it on your view model. There is a method bool **IsNavigationTarget**(NavigationContext ...) which help you identify your view. Also let use **OnNavigatedFrom** method to store NavigationContext parameters, and later use it in IsNavigationTarget method.

Here is example:

```
class MyViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    NavigationContext navigationContext;

    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        this.navigationContext = navigationContext;
    }

    bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
         return Equals(this.navigationContext.Uri, navigationContext.Uri);
    }

    void OnNavigateTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
}

...
// somewhere where you need execute

INotifyCollectionChanged activeViews = RegionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].ActiveViews as INotifyCollectionChanged;
if (activeViews!=null)
{
    activeViews.CollectionChanged += ActiveViews_CollectionChanged;
}


...
Uri modulePreview;

void ActiveViews_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IViewsCollection activeViews = (IViewsCollection)sender;
    NavigationContext navigationContext=new NavigationContext(null, modulePreview);
    activeViews.Any( x=> ((INavigationAware)x).IsNavigationTarget(navigationContext));
}
```